# How to render the value of the updated store on the press of a button?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to figure out how react and redux works. How can i get the value of the store after the press of these three buttons.I'm getting the output on the console but i want it to be displayed on the screen..

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
class Store extends Component {
    render() { 
        const reducer=(state=0,action)=>
        {
            if(action.type==="UPDATE_BONUS")
            {
                return state+action.payload
            }
            if(action.type==="LEVEL_COMPLETED")
            {
                return state+action.payload
            }
            if(action.type==="LIFE_LOST")
            {
                return state-action.payload
            }
            return state;
        }
        const store=createStore(reducer,0);
        store.subscribe(()=>{
            console.log(store.getState());
        })
        const handleUpdateBonus=()=>
        {
        store.dispatch({type:"UPDATE_BONUS",payload:100});
        return (<div>{store.getState()}</div>)
        }
        const handleLevelCompleted=()=>
        {
        store.dispatch({type:"LEVEL_COMPLETED",payload:500});
        return (<div>{store.getState()}</div>)
        }
        const handleLifeLost=()=>
        {
        store.dispatch({type:"LIFE_LOST",payload:250});
        return (<div>{store.getState()}</div>)
        }
        return ( <div>{store.getState()}<button onClick={handleUpdateBonus}>Update-Bonus</button><button onClick={handleLevelCompleted}>Level-Completed</button><button onClick={handleLifeLost}>Life-Lost</button></div> );
    }
}
export default Store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that store.getState() will get evaluated once on render. Because the state is initially zero, it will always show zero. What you want is for the component to re-render every time the state is changed!

For this to happen, you need to connect the component to the store. I would reccomend reading [Redux's documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) on how to do that.

Comment: I know about connect(component)(store) but i don't know how to use it here..I made a seperate component for that and i was trying to connect it  but failed miserably..I need  a simple sample code for it so that i can understand the concept somehow.